# web regression testing suggestions?

Tags: web-services

I am looking for some kind of web regression testing tool. I would like it to be free and also allow me to verify download links.

any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://seleniumhq.org/ - free, programmable, probably close to industry standard.